# Median and square root in Java

Tags: java, median, negative-number

I have to implement a static-public method named “

> berechneMittelwertWurzel

”. The method gets as input parameters a double array and two integer values and returns a double value.
Signature: calculateMeanRoot(double[] array, int startindex, int endindex) : double
The method calculates the mean value from the numbers in the array in the specified range (startIndex to endIndex). From the mean value the square root is calculated and returned.

negative values for both indexes are to be neglected

- if the startIndex > endIndex is an IntervalException should be thrown, which inherits from RuntimeExeption. This should also be callable with a message, but the default constructor should remain.
- if the endIndex > array.length -1 or startIndex < 0, the IndexOutOfBoundsException shall be thrown.
- if the double array is null, 0 shall be returned.
- the result shall be rounded with Math.round().
- If the calculated mean is less than zero (<0), then a NegativeNumberException shall be thrown with an output. The NegativeNumberException must inherit from Exception. The output should be taken from Exception (without its own System.out.println) and contain a suitable text indicating the mean value and the error.

Is there a better way to this ?

```
public static double []  berechneMittelwertWurzel(int startindex, int endindex) {
double arr[] = { 5.2, 66.23, -4.2, 0.0, 53.0 };
 double sum = 0;
 for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  double average = sum / arr.length;
  
  for(int i =0; i < arr.length;i++)
  {
   for(int j = 0;j < arr.length;j++)
      {
          if(Math.sqrt(arr[i]) == arr[j])
          {
              s += arr[j] + "," + arr[i] + " ";
  if(index < 0 || index >= array.length)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Comment: Well, I'd start with implementing the bullet points in order if possible. That means first check the indices and throw exceptions if needed, then return 0 if the array is null or empty and finally do your calcuation. Besides that your task already provided a method signature: `double calculateMeanRoot(double[] array, int startindex, int endindex)`. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: What does “if the double array is null, 0 shall be returned” mean?

Comment: "Is there a better way to this ?" - in short: yes. Why? Because your calculation is wrong. I'm not sure what those inner loops are for but you basically just should do the following: 1) calculate the sum of all elements in the specified range (i.e. at indices `start, start + 1, ... ,end`), 2a) if the sum is negative throw an exception or 2b) if the sum is >= 0 calculate the average by using the length of that range (length can be calculated from the indices) and 3) calculate the square root from that average.

Comment: One final comment: ["mean value"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) and ["median"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) are different things. Since you've used German in your question: `mean value = Mittelwert` (most commonly the average value), `median = Median` (the center/middle value(s) in a series)

Comment: @Thomas In fact, both “Mittelwert” and “average” are rather informal terms that can refer to different values, and both are occasionally used to refer to the median as well as the mean. But confusingly they can also be used to specifically refer to the mean as opposed to the median. Best to avoid them altogether, where it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you’ve posted does not conform to the specification from the exercise. There are various problems:

- Its arguments are wrong
- Its return type is wrong
- It does not check the arguments or throw errors as specified
- Your function seems to create a string (assigned to a variable which isn’t declared!) that is unnecessary to solve the problem

In addition, your question title mentions the *median*; however, you’re attempting to calculate the arithmetic mean. Judging from the question text, this might actually be correct. Just be aware that these two values are generally different.

To fix this, start off from the following signature and fill in the gaps:

```java
public static double calculateMeanRoot(double[] array, int startindex, int endindex) {
    // if the startIndex > endIndex is an IntervalException should be thrown

    // if the endIndex > array.length -1 or startIndex < 0, the IndexOutOfBoundsException shall be thrown

    // calculate the sum of the array elements between `startIndex` and `endIndex` (*)

    // calculate the mean by dividing the sum by the difference between `endIndex` and `startIndex`

    // if the calculated mean is less than zero (<0), then a NegativeNumberException shall be thrown with an output

    // calculate the square root of the mean, round it, and return it
}
```

Only the step annotated with `(*)` requires a loop.

Comment: I'd like to add one correction (based on what I understood from the question): instead of calculating the sum and average for the entire array it seems only the range/sub array between the two indices should be calculated. Code comments 3 and 4 should reflect that.